# Include bootstrap on wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin and i need to add bootstrap on my plugin,so how i included that css,js file.

I have done something like below but it is not working

```
<?php
if( is_admin() ){
    wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap',$plugin_url.'admin/js/bootstrap.min.js',false,'3.3.7',false);

    wp_enqueue_style('admin_css_bootstrap', $plugin_url.'admin/css/bootstrap.min.css',true,'3.3.7','all');
} ?>
```

Comment: anyone know please help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the right action hook for this?

```
<?php
function my_plugin_scripts() {
    if( is_admin() ){
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap',$plugin_url.'admin/js/bootstrap.min.js',false,'3.3.7',false);
        wp_enqueue_style('admin_css_bootstrap', $plugin_url.'admin/css/bootstrap.min.css',true,'3.3.7','all');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );
?>
```

And check whether the paths are right. Use the developer tools of your browser to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('prefix_bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('prefix_bootstrap');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function mw_plugin_scripts() {
  if( is_admin() ){ 
    wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap', plugins_url('admin/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__ ),false,'3.3.7',false);
    wp_enqueue_style('admin_css_bootstrap', plugins_url('admin/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__ ),true,'3.3.7','all'); 
  } 
}  

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mw_plugin_scripts'); 
?>
```

`admin_enqueue_scripts` is the action hooked into the admin scripts actions.

**CHECK FOR THE FOLLOWING THINGS:**

1. Inspect to see the result of your URL and if your path is correct.
2. See if the file exists.

**READ MORE:**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts